# Behat with local Zombie installation

Tags: behat, mink, zombie.js

I'm having troubles with `Zombie.js` and `Behat`. I'm trying to install it locally to the project (as we're trying [not to depend on global packages](https://12factor.net/dependencies)) but I keep getting `Error: Cannot find module 'zombie/node_modules/tough-cookie'` when I run Behat.

Here's my behat.yml

```
default:
  extensions:
    MvLabs\Zf2Extension\Zf2Extension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: 'http://localhost'
      sessions:
        default:
          zombie:
            node_modules_path: ./node_modules/
```

And my `package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "zombie": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

requiring the dev-master version of the mink-zombie-driver package fixes this problem.

```
composer require --dev "behat/mink-zombie-driver dev-master"
```

Comment: I fixed it by installing zombie as a global package. But I don't like globals. Does this work with local zombie installation?

Comment: I tested it today, and it work´s fine. Until my Webpages needs > 5s to respond. Then the behat scenario will fail because you can´t set a zombie timeout in behat.yml. There is a [github PR](https://github.com/minkphp/MinkZombieDriver/pull/154), which will fix this, but not merged till now